# How to fillna efficiently during glob operation of multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, glob, fillna

I have more than 15 csv files. The `csv file 1 to file 4` when loaded as a dataframe look like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,101,101,101],
                        'Date':['06/08/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/01/2014 05:00:00 AM','06/03/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/09/2014 05:00:00 AM'],
                        'Test':['A1','B2','B5','B6']})
```

The `csv file 5 to file 15` look like as shown below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [201,201,201,201],
                        'Date':[np.nan,np.nan,'06/03/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/09/2014 05:00:00 AM'],
                        'Test':['A1','B2','B5','B6'],
                        'date_backup':['03/01/2014 08:00:00 AM','10/08/2014 08:00:00 AM','09/09/2014 08:00:00 AM',np.nan]})
```

As you can see from sample dataframe `df1` (of file 5 to file 15), that I have two `date` columns

Now from `file 5 to file 15`, I would like to fillna in those `date_backup` or `Date` by copying value from the other.

For example, I would like to do the below

```
df1.Date.fillna(df.date_backup, inplace=True)
df1.date_backup.fillna(df.Date, inplace=True)
```

Now, am not sure how can I do the above `fillna()` operation in the below code

I tried the below but not sure whether it is efficient and elegant

```
pat_dir = ['Path1\path2\La*.csv','Path3\Path4\20*.csv']
files_grabbed = []
for files in pat_dir:
    files_grabbed.extend(glob.glob(files))
d = {'date_backup':'Date'}
cols = ['Date','Test','value','person_id']
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, sep=",",low_memory=False).rename(columns=d).reindex(columns=cols) 
       for f in files_grabbed]   #thanks to Jezrael for this code
```

In the code above, you can see that I am renaming the `date_backup` column.

How can I fillna() efficiently and elegantly

I expect my output to be concatenated/appended dataframe of 15 csv files like as shown below (with one Date column). My only question is how can I fillna() before appending dataframes, so I will have only `Date` column

[image]

Comment: If you want to fill the NA of one column with data in another, you can use something like

```df['Col1'].fillna(df['Col2'])```

Comment: I would like to fillna only for the files in which there are two date columns which is `Date` and `date_backup`... If you see file 1 to file 4, we don't have to fillna.. We fillna only for files 5-15

Comment: For files 5 to 15, the same logic for fillna() as shown in sample code in post..

Comment: I got it, need `df1.date_backup.fillna(df1.Date, inplace=True)` not `df1.date_backup.fillna(df.Date, inplace=True)` - working in one DataFrame, not fillna one df by another.

Comment: yes, correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need fillna columns in one DataFrame is possible use `if` statement for `fillna` if exist column `date_backup`:

```
dfs= []
for f in files_grabbed:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(f, sep=",",low_memory=False)
    if 'date_backup' in df1.columns:
        df1.Date = df1.Date.fillna(df1.date_backup)
      
    #not sure if necessary rename and reindex
    df1 = df1.rename(columns=d).reindex(columns=cols) 
    dfs.append(df1)
```

Another idea is add `date_backup` for each `DataFrame` and `fillna` after `concat`:

```
cols = ['Date','Test','value','person_id', 'date_backup']
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, sep=",",low_memory=False).rename(columns=d).reindex(columns=cols) 
   for f in files_grabbed] 


df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.Date = df.Date.fillna(df.pop('date_backup'))
```